# Indexing all integer partitions of all integers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Basically, a function that gives each partition of each integer a corresponding number i.e.:
$$
\begin{matrix}
(\:\:) & (1)  & (1,1) & (2) & (1,1,1) & (2,1) & (3) & \ldots\\
\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \ldots \\
\end{matrix}
$$
or maybe:
\begin{matrix}
(\:\:) & (1)  & (2) & (1,1) & (3) & (2,1) & (1,1,1) & \ldots\\
\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \ldots \\
\end{matrix}

(There's no need for an order like the examples but that would seem like the easiest way to do this)

The way I'm currently doing this is using an algorithm to index all partition of sum $n$ then adding that index to $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}p(i)$, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way of doing this. I feel like it could be related to Young's lattice, but I don't have any clue where I should be looking. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about overall order? i.e. do the partitions of 2 have to have greater index than the partitions of 1, and lesser index than the partitions of 3?

Comment: Also, is it acceptable to generate them recursively?

Comment: @Kajelad As I’ve (apparently not very clearly) said on the post, the overall order does not matter. The less recursion the better.

Comment: Are you trying to find that $(13,9,7,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ is the millionth on your list or the other way round? Are you willing to use pre-programmed functions? Can you state an upper limit to which partitions you are interested in?

Comment: There is an old paper by Thomas Brylawski "[The lattice of integer partitions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73900940)" which address this problem and the far more wider family of related ordering problems.

Comment: @Henry just the first one, though i’m guessing there’s probably gonna be a way to reverse the process anyways. What exactly do you mean by pre programmed functions? No particular upper limit, but for the most part the largest sum won’t be exceeding 10000.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thanks for the suggestion will read up on that.

Comment: Have you checked Section 5.8 in Nicholas Loehr, *Bijective Combinatorics*, 2011, and possibly §7.2.1.4 of Donald Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, volume 4A? I don't think any of them gives a particularly direct bijection between positive integers and all integer partitions, but they look like a good starting point if you can quickly compute the partition numbers $p\left(n\right)$ and $p\left(n,k\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the overall order does not matter, indexing the set of partitions of positive integers is the same as indexing the set of finite multisets of positive integers, so you could use the following bijection:
$$(i_1^{m_1},i_2^{m_2},\ldots,i_k^{m_k})\ \longleftrightarrow\ p_{i_1}^{m_1}\cdot p_{i_2}^{m_2}\cdots p_{i_k}^{m_k}
$$
where the LHS is string notation for the multiset composed of "$m_1$ copies of positive integer $i_1 $, $m_2$ copies of positive integer $i_2,\ldots,\ m_k$ copies of positive integer $i_k $", with $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_k,$ and the RHS is the corresponding prime factorization with $p_i$denoting the $i$th prime. Thus:
$$\begin{align}()&\leftrightarrow 1\\
(1)&\leftrightarrow 2^1\\
(2)&\leftrightarrow 3^1\\
(3)&\leftrightarrow 5^1\\
&...\\
(1,1)&\leftrightarrow 2^2\\
(1,2)&\leftrightarrow 2^1\cdot 3^1\\
(2,3)&\leftrightarrow 3^1\cdot 5^1\\
&...\\
(1,1,1,3,6,6)&\leftrightarrow 2^3\cdot 5^1\cdot 13^2\\
&...
\end{align}$$

Comment: Completely forgot about primes! Ironically enough it should have come to mind pretty quickly with p being used for both primes and partitions. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there be a way to do this if the overall order did matter? ( Also should I post another question for this I’m new here).

Comment: There's a lot of literature cited in various OEIS references & cross-references; e.g., at http://oeis.org/A036036, etc